# Symfony 3 - debug TWIG not working

Tags: php, symfony

I have just installed Symfony 3 on my Windows MAMP Pro server. (Apache).

Everything works fine expect that the debbuging bar for TWIG doesn't work.
[image]

[image]

The config.php tells me that my server is running well for Symfony and Debug::enable(); is enabled in my app_dev.php.

Any idea why TWIG debug do not work?

Answer (score 0):

After some headache moments I figured out that I was on prod mode and not in dev mode.. ( I didn't know that the debug bar also appears in prod mode)